# PIL/Pillow convert Image to list and back again

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to open an RGB picture, convert it to grayscale, then represent it as a list of floats scaled from 0 to 1. At last, I want to convert it back again to an Image. However, in the code below, something in my conversion procedure fails, as `img.show()` (the original image) displays correctly while `img2.show()` display an all black picture. What am I missing?

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

ocr_img_path = "./ocr-test.jpg"

# Open image, convert to grayscale
img = Image.open(ocr_img_path).convert("L")

# Convert to list
img_data = img.getdata()
img_as_list = np.asarray(img_data, dtype=float) / 255
img_as_list = img_as_list.reshape(img.size)

# Convert back to image
img_mul = img_as_list * 255
img_ints = np.rint(img_mul)
img2 = Image.new("L", img_as_list.shape)
img2.putdata(img_ints.astype(int))

img.show()
img2.show()
```

[The image used](https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2014/08/07/21/13/newspaper-412811_960_720.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to flatten the array before putting it into the image. I think PIL interprets multidimensional arrays as different color bands.

```
img2.putdata(img_ints.astype(int).flatten())
```

For a more efficient way of loading images, check out

> https://blog.eduardovalle.com/2015/08/25/input-images-theano/

but use `image.tobytes()` (Pillow) instead of `image.tostring()` (PIL).
.